# is it possible to extend soci and use wxVector instead of vector for bulk operations?

Tags: wxwidgets, soci

is it possible to extend soci database library and use `wxVector` instead of `std::vector` for bulk operations?

I know how to extend the basic data-types, but for bulk operations, I have no idea.

Comment: why do you want to use an outdated class? Vadim (and other core devs) recommend using std::vector whenever possible. Using wxVector is for backward compatibility only and is discouraged in the new code.

Comment: No way! I have never heard about that, I have never heard about dropping `wxVector` in the future either. Give me a link to what you are saying.

Comment: I believe its been repeatedly said that all wx containers classes will be for internal use only and the newly written code should prefer to use the STL classes. I don't have any links right now, but if you look at the blogs for wx and search ML archive you will find it. But this is beside the point. Why do you want to use something that was created to cover non-existent classes.

Comment: Remember - all those wxVector/wxList/wxHashMap, etc, was created to have container classes for the compilers that didn't support the STL back in 1990th when the library was created. There is no specific reason to use now especially with C++11/14/17. Unless you working on some very ancient software with some very ancient compiler (DigitalMars?, Watcom?) that does not support STL containers.

Comment: I myself use the library -wxShapeFramework, which was made with the wxList/wxVector. I'd very much like to update it to use STL containers, but I'm not sure if this is something I'm allowed to do. Besides I'm just a user of this library and I believe the authors of it was moved on a long time ago. So as long as it works...

Comment: OK, fair enough, I will stick to `std::vector` then.